# High current load from low current source

Tags: power-supply

If a device requires 500 mA current (Specification) and let's say I have a power supply with max current of 100mA. What is likely to happen and why.?

Comment: What kind of power supply? What kind of device? In general, in the case you described 100mA will be drawn from a power supply, but your device won't work. However, depending on the parameters of the supply and the load, there may be additional constraints.

Comment: You will bring down the power supply voltage.  The rest depends on the design of the 100mA power supply.  If it doesn't have over-current protection, it could burn.  If there is a fuse, it will open.  If there is a crowbar circuit, it will turn off the supply.  If there is a μC, it will reset.

Comment: You're asking a question about specification abuse.  But, you're not providing justification as to why you might get away with this abuse.  Broad question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: I am sorry for posting the incomplete question.Power supply is regultaed one.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the source, and to a lesser extent the target device.

If the source has circuitry to specifically limit the current, that circuitry will kick in if the load exceeds a certain limit, so the device will only receive a smaller portion of the current it "wants", usually causing source voltage to droop.

If the source has Over-Current-Protection, thermal overload protection, etc., it could temporarily or permanently shut off. Resetting the source could require replacing a fuse, waiting for a polyfuse to cool down, flipping a circuit-breaker, waiting for IC automatic timers to reset, etc.

If it has no specific protection circuitry what-so-ever, it would try to source whatever the device asks for. Since is was not specified to handles these loads, we enter the land of `Undefined Behavior(tm)`. It could work just happily, catch on fire due to thermal overload, have some quasi-output current limit, or some combination of the three (work one day, catch fire another day).

This is just a `Bad Idea(tm)`. At best your device and source might work, at worst you're going to end up with a damaged equipment, potential fire hazards, and a bad day.

This is by no means a conclusive list of what could happen, but I think covers most "common cases".

Comment: suppose the voltage supply is 5V, but the load requires 10V threshold voltage - below this voltage it's input impedance is infinite. Is your answer applicable to these conditions?

Comment: That is known as brown-out, and some devices do have brown-out detection/handling. Usually the device would enter a "shutdown-mode" and just not turn on until the voltage exceeds the brown-out voltage limit. If not, again we enter the land of `Undefined Behavior(tm)` and your guess is as good as mine (without further information of the actual source/device). Again, another `Bad Idea(tm)`.

Comment: Indeed. I think there should be no answers unless additional information is provided in the question.